# How old is the Millennium Falcon?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, age, millennium-falcon

From what I've heard Star Wars is still using tech from thousands of years prior, and while there are innovations, older craft can still compete with newer craft. So how old is the *Millennium Falcon*? In the real world you can use a 747 for about 20-40 years (depending on use and the quality of repairs/maintenance). The *Falcon* seems to be a pile of junk, by the time Han solo has it, other than being extremely fast.

Comment: Legends acceptable?

Comment: She may not look like much, but she's got it where it counts, kid.

Comment: @null everything is open for this

Comment: You want real world old?  The last [B-52 bomber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_B-52_Stratofortress) rolled off the assembly line in 1962. 50 years later (and with many upgrades and modifications) the US is still flying those airframes as their primary front line bomber and plans on it through 2040... 80 years!

Comment: @Schwern yeah i know where still using some pretty old f16's, and until that new design theyve been working on for the last 10 years is finally done, they will continue using these f 16s lol.

Comment: C-130s and Boeing 707s date back to the 1950's and are still in use.  Somewhere, at least one WWII B-29 Super Fortress is kept functional by an enthusiast. Keeping most machines working is more a matter of maintenance than usefulness. Research old European clocks if you're interested in how long machines can last and still work.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

At the time of *A New Hope*:

### Canon - 51+ years

According to the [*Millennium Falcon* IncrediBuilds book](http://www.simonandschuster.com/books/IncrediBuilds-Star-Wars-Millennium-Falcon-Deluxe-Book-and-Model-Set/Michael-Kogge/9781682980101), she's been flying the friendly skies for over ninety years by the time of the First Order (emphasis mine):

> There are legendary ships, and then there's the *Millennium Falcon*. **For over nine decades**, this YT-1300 freighter has sailed across the stars, doing so much more than hauling cargo. Under captains like Lando Calrissian and Han Solo, she's been involved in notorious gambling exchanges and epic smuggling capers. She's outraced kilometer-long star cruisers and holds an unconfirmed record for the Kessel Run. She's even helped topple the Galactic Empire and **played a part in winning desperate battles against the First Order.**

If we make the assumption that this is dating from the time of *The Force Awakens* (which seems reasonable), then the *Falcon* would have been built no later than 24 years **before** the events of *The Phantom Menace*<sup>1</sup>. Since *A New Hope* takes place [27 years after](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/135519/31051) *The Phantom Menace*, the *Falcon* would have been at least 51 years old in that film.

### Legends - 60 years

The first chapter of the 2008 novel [*Millenium Falcon*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Millennium_Falcon_(novel)) depicts her first day off the assembly line, in the year 60 BBY:

> CORELLIAN ENGINEERING CORPORATION ORBITAL ASSEMBLY FACILITY 7
> 60 YEARS BEFORE THE BATTLE OF YAVIN
>
> *[...]*
>
> Kantt swung back to the transparisteel pane. The droid hadn't moved and was probably continuing to pump fuel into [YT 492727ZED](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Millennium_Falcon/Legends#The_early_years).
>
> *[...]*
>
> "That YT," he added when Kantt glanced at him. "A hero's birth if I ever witnessed one. When has that happened?"
>
> Kantt made a face. "It's a freighter, Bon. One of a hundred million."
>
> Bon grinned. "If you ask me, more like one in a hundred million."
>
> <sup>*Star Wars: Millenium Falcon* Chapter 1</sup>

So the *Falcon* is 60 years old in *A New Hope*.

---

<sup>1</sup> According [to Leland Chee](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/135519/31051), *Return of the Jedi* took place 36 years after *The Phantom Menace*, and *The Force Awakens* took place [30 years after that](http://www.starwars.com/films/star-wars-episode-vii-the-force-awakens). [`(36+30)-90 = -24`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(36%2B30)-90)

Comment: Still pretty fresh then, in spaceship years

Comment: I should have answered first and asked if Legends was acceptable later. :)

Comment: @Null There's a "Han shot first" joke in there, but I'm not going to make it

Comment: Is there confirmation that YT-1300 in *RotS* is the Falcon in-universe, and not just another random YT-1300?

Comment: @phantom42 According to Wookieepedia, Lucas did confirm this. Unfortunately the page they cite has been taken down, so I'm trying to find another source

Comment: @phantom42 Found it in the Wayback Machine. Even if they don't quote him directly, I'm inclined to accept StarWars.com's authority on this one

Comment: @SaturnsEye How do convert my cat's age to spaceship years?

Comment: @Lexible Subtract 9, multiply by 42, convert to parsecs, and blend on medium until slightly crisp.

Comment: I read your first highlighted part in the announcer's voice for the N64 Rouge Squadron game