# What is the time span of the Prequel Trilogy and Original Trilogy?

Tags: star-wars, timeline

Can someone provide a time table or timeline image of the Original Trilogy? I would appreciate if the Prequels timeline will be posted as well.

[This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16131) discussed about, as I understand, the time span or *how long each movie happened*, e.g. *The Phantom Menace* happened for *less than one year*, *Attack of the Clones* happened for about *13 days*, so on and so forth..

What I would like to know is how long (whether canon, in-universe, out-universe, or other stuff) did the prequel trilogy and original trilogy take place, e.g. the Prequels (from *The Phantom Menace* to *Revenge of the Sith*) is **XX years**, then after XX years, *Rogue One* took place, then after XX years, the original trilogy took place.

All I know is that ***The Force Awakens* happened 30 years after *Return of the Jedi***.

PS: It doesn't have to be in *years*. Months, or even days, are also measured in timelines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Leland Chee](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Leland_Chee), of the [Lucasfilm Story Group](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lucasfilm_Story_Group) in charge of *Star Wars* continuity, tweeted a timeline using Episode I as year 0:

[image]

([image from Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/File:2016-03-21_001420.jpg), original tweet [here](https://twitter.com/HolocronKeeper/status/495972415458250752))

A separate tweet specifies the films/cartoons from that tweet:

[image]

(link to tweet [here](https://twitter.com/HolocronKeeper/status/495968283150286848))

Therefore **the prequel trilogy spans 13 years and the original trilogy spans 4 years, with a 19 year gap between the two trilogies.**

The exact date for *Rogue One* isn't known yet but it takes place shortly before Episode IV (since the Rebels attempt to acquire the Death Star's plans in it).

Wookieepedia has a nice [timeline of canon media](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Timeline_of_canon_media) which collects all this information into a single timeline.

Comment: You sir deserve an upvote..and a cookie.

Comment: @Aogiri A [gold tag badge](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/106/star-wars?userid=31936), too. :)